# nodejs agenda repeats the same job

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my code agendasetup.js I have the output below. So command-0,target-0, etc instead of command-1,target-1, etc How to tell agenda to run different jobs ?

> *$node agendasetup.js*

command-1
target-1
time-1
Host

command-1
target-1
time-1
Host

**agendasetup.js:**

```
var config = require('./../config/config');
var devagenda = require('./../modules/agendajob');
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: config.agenda_uri}});

for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    command = 'command-'+i;target = 'target-'+i;
    time = 'time-'+i; host='Host';
    agenda.define('renew cert', function(job, done) {
        devagenda(command, target, time, host);
        done();
    });
    agenda.schedule('in 5 seconds', 'renew cert');
    agenda.start();
}
```

**./../modules/agendajob**

```
module.exports = function devagenda(command,target, time, host) {
    console.log(command+'\n'+target+'\n'+ time+'\n'+host+'\n');
};
```

Comment: using node, if you enable harmony flag, solution would be as simple as putting `let` before all of those variables defined inside your loop. `let i=0;` for example. and don't forget `'use strict';`

Comment: I run 'node --harmony agendasetup.js' , added let to i, command, target, time and host but still the same output with '-1's: 
command-1
target-1
time-1
Host

command-1
target-1
time-1
Host I added also "use strict"; at the beginning of the code

Comment: Oh, you're defining the same job multiple times too, so that's also an issue. If they're all named 'renew cert' how is agenda supposed to know which one to run? It likely only stores the last one.

Comment: Oh I think it worked after I added let jobname = command+target+time; I tried before but without --harmony.. Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using node, and assuming it's a more recent version of node, you can enable the harmony flag by adding --harmony to your start command, and then make a few modifications to the script to use the new es6 `let` syntax to fix the for loop scope issue.

```
'use strict';
var config = require('./../config/config');
var devagenda = require('./../modules/agendajob');
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: config.agenda_uri}});

for (let i=0; i<2; i++) {
    let command = 'command-'+i;
    let target = 'target-'+i;
    let time = 'time-'+i; 
    let host='Host';
    let jobname = command+target+time
    agenda.define(jobname, function(job, done) {
        devagenda(command, target, time, host);
        done();
    });
    agenda.schedule('in 5 seconds', 'renew cert');
    agenda.start();
}
```

---

For older versions of node (or usage without harmony flag), you can use an iife inside the for loop.

```
var config = require('./../config/config');
var devagenda = require('./../modules/agendajob');
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: config.agenda_uri}});

for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var command = 'command-'+i;
        var target = 'target-'+i;
        var time = 'time-'+i;
        var host='Host';
        agenda.define('renew cert', function(job, done) {
            devagenda(command, target, time, host);
            done();
        });
        agenda.schedule('in 5 seconds', 'renew cert');
        agenda.start();
    }(i));
}
```